# Don't indent Xcode-style commented-out code

Tags: xcode, comments, clang-format

Is there currently a way (other than explicitly suppressing formatting for a code segment) to get clang-format to not indent Xcode-style commented out code? That's `//` at the beginning of the line:

```
int f()
{
//    return 1;
    return 2;
}
```

Xcode does this comment-out style on Cmd+`/`.

clang-format, when run, indents the comment:

```
int f()
{
    //    return 1;
    return 2;
}
```

which Xcode still successfully uncomments-out using the same shortcut, but resulting in inconsistent indentation:

```
int f()
{
        return 1;
    return 2;
}
```

I tried (ab)using `CommentPragmas` for this purpose, unsuccessfully. I thought maybe I'm doing the spaces in the regex wrong, but even with `CommentPragmas: '^aaaa'`:

```
int f()
{
//aaaareturn 1;
    return 2;
}
```

gets indented to

```
int f()
{
    //aaaareturn 1;
    return 2;
}
```

So either I'm still doing something wrong, or `CommentPragmas` will still indent comments, even if not otherwise re-flowing them.